# css to position a form on top of an image in a layout table

Tags: css, forms, alignment

I was trying to place a form over an image that I wanted to have it as a background in my whole homepage. Everything works fine. The only problem is that I want to place table some pixels lets 50 more to down. Also I would like to place table not to the end of right, but lets say 30 pixels before of it. Any ideas ?

This is my html code:

```
<html>

<head>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="text">

<div class="homepageTable"     width:40px;   margin-right:auto;   margin-left:auto;   style="text-align:right" >
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <input type="text"  size="25"  name="first_name"        placeholder="first name"><br/>
                <input type="text"  size="25"  name="last_name"         placeholder="last name"><br/>
                <input type="text"  size="25"  name="email"             placeholder="email"><br/>
                <input type="text"  size="25"  name="retype_email"      placeholder="retype your email"><br/>
                <input type="text"  size="25"  name="password"          placeholder="password"><br/>
                <input type="text"  size="25"  name="retype_password2"  placeholder="retype your password"><br/><br/>

                    <input type="checkbox" name="I_accept_terms" value=" "><br/>

                <input type="submit" value="" name="submit" style="background:url('img/login_button_1.jpg') no-repeat; width:300; height:50; border:none;"/>

            </form>
        </div> 

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my css file:

```
#text 
{
width: 961px;
height:219px;
position: relative;
background-image: url(../img/back_img_green.jpg);
background-repeat: none;
}
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks Stefanos

Comment: I'm confused. Can you clarify exactly what the desired result is, and what isn't working in your code example?  "Any ideas?" isn't a good question - it doesn't help us understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Also, is this question different that your previous questions?

Comment: Formatting the attributes of tags into columns? EEK!

Comment: I just want to move form over background image...lets say 50px left and 30px down. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely position the image inside a relatively positioned div. Then absolutely position the form by the offset from top left that you want and give the form a higher z-index. Either that or set the image to be the background of the div.

Comment: looks good... but can you describe this using some code please? thanks

Comment: oh... yes I see what you mean "pixelator". It works. Thank you!